# how can i display uploaded image from a folder in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, razor-pages

I have a folder which stores attachments of different types with specified prefix.
For example,the image attachment will have "IM-" prefix and document attachment will have "DOC" prefix.
What i need is i want to display the Image attachment only in view page.
How i can get ImageFileName in OnGet method. Here is my Code,

Biodata.cshtml.cs

```
//--------------------Image Upload ---------------//
    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile StaffPhoto { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGetAsync(int? StaffID)
    {
        StaffGender = new SelectList(_context.Gender, "StaffGender", "StaffGender");
        StaffReligion = new SelectList(_context.Religion, "StaffReligion", "StaffReligion");            
        StaffBioData = await _context.StaffBioData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.StaffID == StaffID);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents/OnBoardingAttachments", StaffBioData.EmpID.ToString()));
        
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateBioDataAsync(StaffBioData StaffBioData)
    {
        StaffGender = new SelectList(_context.Gender, "StaffGender", "StaffGender");
        StaffReligion = new SelectList(_context.Religion, "StaffReligion", "StaffReligion");
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            var biodata = from u in _context.StaffBioData select u;
            biodata = biodata.Where(s => s.StaffID.Equals(StaffBioData.StaffID));
            StaffIDExists = biodata.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
            _context.Entry(StaffBioData).State = StaffIDExists == null?
                               EntityState.Added :
                               EntityState.Modified;                
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var filesave = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents/OnBoardingAttachments", StaffBioData.EmpID, "IM-" + StaffBioData.EmpID + StaffPhoto.FileName);
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filesave))
            {
                await StaffPhoto.CopyToAsync(stream);
                //TempData["Success"] = "Success";
                ImageName = "IM-" + StaffBioData.EmpID + StaffPhoto.FileName;
            }
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
```

Biodata.cshtml

```
<!-- Photo -->
            <div class="form-group">                
                <label class="control-label-staff"><b>Photo</b></label>
                  <span>
                    <br />
                    <img src="~/Documents/OnBoardingAttachments/@Request.Query["EmpID"].ToString()/@Model.ImageName" />
                  </span>
                  <input type="file" asp-for="StaffPhoto" class="form-control-staff" accept="image/*" style="border:1px solid white;margin-right:20px" />               
            </div>
```

Whats happening now is in the edit screen im not getting the value for @Model.ImageName
My folder will have other files also,but i need to display only the file with prefix "IM-"
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @Teena,Did my answer help you resolve issue?

Comment: Hi @ Rena,Sorry i will check this , i already solved the issue by someother method.After that only i got this solution.Let me check once. if it works i will mark it as a solution.thank you so much for the support

Comment: Ok.Glad that you have resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how to display only file with prefix `IM-`,please check the following code:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(int? StaffID)           
{
    StaffGender = new SelectList(_context.Gender, "StaffGender", "StaffGender");
    StaffReligion = new SelectList(_context.Religion, "StaffReligion", "StaffReligion");
    StaffBioData = await _context.StaffBioData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.StaffID == StaffID);
    var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents/OnBoardingAttachments", StaffBioData.EmpID.ToString()));
    foreach(var path in filePath)
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        if(name.StartsWith("IM-"))
        {
            ImageName = name;
        }
    }          
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi@Rena, im getting the following error, 'The type or namespace name "GetFiles" doesnot exist in the current namespace.

Comment: Hi @Teena,be sure add `using System.IO; ` or use:`System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)`

Comment: Hi @Rena, im using System.IO and im not having issue with GetFileName, The error is showing for Directory.GetFiles

Comment: Hi @Teena,oh sorry,I make mistake.Your error should be here:`var filePath = Directory.GetFiles`.It is Directory not Path.

Comment: var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(... ,so you are saying instead of Path,it should be Directory.ryt?

Comment: Sorry that maybe what i said make you confused.Just try this:`var filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents/OnBoardingAttachments", StaffBioData.EmpID.ToString()));` And check if still make error.And am I right you make error in this line?

Comment: Hi @Rena, Yes now the error has gone.Thanks for the support.

Comment: My pleasure! :)